# PInvoke with pointers - C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, com, pinvoke

The following is a PInvoke block in C++ that I'm trying to convert to C#:

```
typedef  PVOID   JHANDLE ;
typedef  UINT32  JRET ;

#define JEXPORT __declspec(dllimport) JRET

JEXPORT
JInitialize (
   OUT JHANDLE* ppHandle,
   IN  PVOID       context,  
   IN  UINT32      flags
) ;
```

I tried the following call, but it threw a PInvokeStackImbalance exception saying that the signatures don't match:

```
[DllImport("jhi.dll")]
public static extern UInt32 JHI_Initialize(out IntPtr ppHandle, IntPtr context, UInt32 flags);
```

Obviously a pointer of a pointer is handled different, but I'm not exactly sure how it translates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the CallingConvention in your [DllImport] declaration, it is Cdecl.

Comment: Thanks, I always forget about CallingConvention

Comment: I know this is ancient and the OP's problem doesn't really match mine, but this answer just saved me after many hours of pInvoke hell.  You get a vote.